# Error: ActionItem is not a valid View instance

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have the following template:

```
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Modules" automationText="ActionBar">
        <NavigationButton icon="res://back_btn" tap="goBack" automationText="GoBack"></NavigationButton>
        <Android>
            <ActionItem id="exampleMenuButton" icon="res://menu" automationText="ExampleMenu"></ActionItem>
        </Android>
        <iOS>
            <ActionItem id="exampleMenuButton" ios.position="right" automationText="ExampleMenu">
                <ActionItem.actionView>
                    <Image src="res://menu" width="22" height="22" margin="0, -11, 0, 11"></Image>
                </ActionItem.actionView>
            </ActionItem>
        </iOS>
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>
```

Which comes from [nativescript-marketplace-demo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-marketplace-demo/blob/release/app/examples/layouts/layouts-example.xml). First I had to change tags to be not self-closed, because of `Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "NavigationButton"`-like errors and now get the error seen below, why?

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/vendor.js:1688:24: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: ActionItem is not a valid View instance.
_addView@file:///app/vendor.js:77124:28 [angular]
addChild@file:///app/vendor.js:79138:22 [angular]
insertChild@file:///app/vendor.js:58553:32 [angular]
appendChild@file:///app/vendor.js:57775:38 [angular]
appendChild@file:///app/vendor.js:13726:34 [angular]
createElement@file:///app/vendor.js:9925:33 [angular]
createViewNodes@file:///app/vendor.js:12532:57 [angular]
callViewAction@file:///app/vendor.js:12944:28 [angular]
execComponentViewsAction@file:///app/vendor.js:12883:27 [angular]
createViewNodes@file:///app/vendor.js:12601:29 [angular]
createRootView@file:///app/vendor.js:12479:20 [angular]
callWithDebugContext@file:///app/vendor.js:13610:47 [angular]
create@file:///app/vendor.js:10415:60 [angular]
createComponent@file:///app/vendor.js:10615:68 [angular]
activateOnGoForward@file:///app/vendor.js:48567:70 [angular]
activateWith@file:///app/vendor.js:48553:37 [angular]
placeComponentIntoOutlet@file:///app/vendor.js:23184:28 [angular]
activateRoutes@file:///app/vendor.js:23165:50 [angular]
file:///app/vendor.js:23101:72 [angular]
forEach@[native code] [angular]
activateChildRoutes@file:///app/vendor.js:23101:36 [angular]
activate@file:///app/vendor.js:23075:33 [angular]
file:///app/vendor.js:22692:30 [angular]
file:///app/vendor.js:230:25 [angular]
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML template you attempted to use is a PAN (**P**lain **A**wesome **N**ativeScript) file, not a NAN (**N**ativeScript **AN**gular) file.

This is actually very critical to understand, some things work only in PAN and somethings only work in NAN.  They are written very similar, but there are several key differences...

For example in PAN it is tagged as a .XML file, in NAN it is normally tagged as a HTML file.  In PAN, you have the *Page* tag, in NAN, you normally skip the *Page* tag and use the *Router* tag.   In PAN all your tags can optionally be self closed.  In NAN, all tags better not be self closed at all.

In PAN all events are treated like any other property in the xml file; i.e. `tap="goback"`. is the same as `label="hi"` In NAN, that tap event should be written as `(tap)="goback()"`

These are only a few of the differences, there are many others that make the two formats incompatible with each other without you making changes to the screen.

Since it appears you are attempting to learn NAN, I would recommend you checkout the 
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/ example application.  This APP is fully written in NAN.

In addition the http://docs.nativescript.org has full documentation for both PAN and NAN apps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's very helpful. I actually use the sample-Groceries project you mentioned as my starting point, but I'm just beginning the play with Nativescript UI and wasn't aware of these different models, thanks for clarification!